# Timer on swift not working

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have a function working with a button:

```
@IBAction func btnSiguiente(_ sender: Any) {
    if indexImagenes == imagenes.count {
        indexImagenes = 0
    }
    escaparate.image = NSImage(named: imagenes[indexImagenes])
    indexImagenes += 1
}
```

I want to make it work with a Timer:

```
 var playTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(autoplay), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func autoplay() {
    if indexImagenes == imagenes.count {
        indexImagenes = 0
    }
    escaparate.image = NSImage(named: imagenes[indexImagenes])
    indexImagenes += 1
}
```

But I get this in console:
[_SwiftValue autoplay]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000451c0

Comment: try `playTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(autoplay), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Comment: When you create the timer, what is `self`?

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, initialize the timer once the instance of the class your are in is fully initialized.

So just give the var playTimer a default value as follows:

```
var playerTimer:Timer? = nil
```

Then initialize the timer in some function that gets called once 'self' is fully initialized  (like viewDidLoad() for example, assuming this code is in a viewController):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playerTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(autoplay), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Essentially just make sure 'self' is fully initialized before you send it a selector to perform.

Comment: Excellent! Yeah always make sure the object your sending a method call to is fully instantiated.